# Correct way to handle maintenance mode from a Database setting

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-503, maintenance-mode

building a CMS and looking to find out the correct way of showing a maintenance mode message to users.

My plan is to have the option in my admin backend. I already have the table in my DB for website config and i have a field that just has a value. I was using 1 for normal and 2 for maintenance mode. I just want to be able to update the database.

My question is however, whats the proper way to do this?

My first thought was to check the DB and then if the value is "2" i would redirect the user (all PHP) to e.g. 503.php.

But i have also seen that a better way is in the .htaccess and then i can allow a certain IP to still have access. But can this in the .htaccess be managed from a database check?

Looking to do things properly so curious as the the 'standards' way of doing this.

Is my first suggestion feasible? The main reason for the 'maintenance mode' is actually to protect myself. My site has gone through lots of testing, but i want a way i can quickly shut down access to the site (SEO freindly) just whilst i fix any issues. Or whilst i am updating the site itself.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps do a cron job to check every minute what the value in the db is. If it's `true` edit the .htaccess file to include your 503 for all IPs except yours.

Comment: This is really an opinion-based question.  What one person defines as "maintenance mode" may be totally different from another. You also have not been really specific at all in talking about your desired behavior or your system architecture which may allow for other options (like removing a host that is under maintenance from a load balancer).

Comment: Just added couple of updates to my question. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just go with using source control? That way you can work locally and pull the changes through once fixed.

Comment: The most SEO friendly way of maintenance is to have partial maintenance. You normally do not need to shutdown the whole site. Also like others did comment: if something didn't work out with testing earlier, switch the site back to the previous version, test on a second host, then re-deploy the next version. that is normally without downtime then.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't control the maintenance mode setting from the database, if you don't have to.

The database adds another layer of complexity which may fail at some point.

In practice, you have a few options:

1. Add a text file with the setting for maintenance mode. Prior to serving a request, use PHP to open and read the value of the file. Then, you can handle it appropriately by issuing a redirect if needed.
2. Use an external service like [Pingometer](http://pingometer.com) to monitor your site(s). This automates the process and, if any of them go down, use their web hook functionality to send a request to a PHP script that switches this value (perhaps using the method described in #1) to maintenance mode.

I think your goal is that, if happens to the site (externally), your maintenance mode is automatically tripped -- #1 and #2 offer an easy solution.